# FYI: A second apology from SE has been posted

Tags: discussion

[An apology to our community, and next steps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps)

A good sign. Hopefully they will follow through well and all [mods who have resigned will return, assuming they want to](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5765/moderator-resignation#comment19187_5773).

Glen_b has already referred to this in an update to the [Moderator resignation](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5765/moderator-resignation) post. I'm sharing this as a new post for those who are not checking updates and may have missed the latest episode in this fracas.

**Edit**: Unfortunately, [the follow-through has been very poor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334646/364758) so far. It increasingly appears that the apology was disingenuous.

**Edit 2**: Along with the lack of action to fix the earlier problems, [a new FAQ on gender pronouns and the code of conduct changes is proving deeply unpopular](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes). gung has a [comment](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/fyi-a-second-better-apology-from-se-has-been-posted?noredirect=1#comment19200_5774) about it below.

Comment: Yep - to clarify: the fact that resigning mods could return if they want was already the the situation before this began.

Comment: @Glen_b I should have said 'will', not 'can'. Edited.

Comment: I thought "can" was correct; just wanted to make it clear there was already a policy about that rather than something done in response to the recent events.

Comment: The issue has always been **whether @MonicaCellio could return**, not the tons of moderators who resigned in protest at her blatant mistreatment and the false accounts put out by SO corporate, namely that she did not violate the CoC in place. The second apology tries to shroud that in secrecy and obfuscation: *"We’ll be reaching out to her directly to apologize for the lack of process[!], privacy, and to discuss next steps. We’ll keep those discussions completely private unless we both agree to share any of it with the community."*

Comment: @smci In case I wasn't clear, rectifying the situation with Monica Cellio was implied by "Hopefully they will follow through well". There's plenty of discussion of the merits and problems with the apology at the linked thread; my goal was not to summarise the situation, but to make people aware of a recent development.

Comment: @smci For some moderators this crisis has been something like last nail in the coffin. I have seen meta posts where they say that they had been contemplating this decision for long. This crisis doesn't seem the right way for moderators to leave the community that they served with keen interest and devotion. They deserve much better.

Comment: @mkt: ok but I don't understand why you couldn't just post the basic facts without the narrative, 'good sign', 'hopefully' etc. The second apology is less bad than the first, but still weasell, dishonest and utterly inadequate for the reasons I spelled out. So if the first apology scored an F, this is an E-. This matter is not over yet, not at all. I can't see that the phrase *"We made a big mistake, we were wrong, we apologize to Monica Cellio and she was been reinstated"* is so complicated to utter. 'Next steps' is simply weaselly...

Comment: ...It's up to all us SO userbase to decide who in SO corporate needs to apologize or be fired for this garbage. One SO employee's name springs very much to mind, and she hasn't apologized. Also, why has new CEO Prashanth Chandrasekar been so very conspicuously silent? The buck stops with him. [Hiding behind David Fullerton](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps) is cowardly. Tell [Prasanth](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/pchandrasekar_rackers-stackoverflow-rackspace-activity-6582282554869641216-06ta/) all about this on LinkedIn.

Comment: ...also the fact that [ex-CEO Joel Spolsky, the man who volunteers opinions on almost everything, is also mysteriously silent since Sept 24](https://twitter.com/spolsky). Since telling us what a great leap forward Prashanth's appointment was, ironically. And Spolsky is still Chairman, so the buck stops with him too.

Comment: @smci My primary goal was to inform, but I thought a minor, cautiously optimistic note was warranted (those few words hardly constitute a narrative). You're welcome to post more details in an answer or a new thread if this one offends you.

Comment: [Previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps#comment1097594_334551) I stated that I was retracting my upvote, but might reupvote or downvote later. In light of [the heavy handed change to the CoC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334900/187282) (which is inconsistent w/ my & other mods' comments on the drafts), & the lack of satisfactory action on Monica's case, I am forced to conclude that the 2nd 'apology' was insincere & was a stalling tactic to buy time & hope this blows over. I have now downvoted it.

Comment: Certainly Monica is dissatisfied with he current situation. It sounds like she got sent one email after the second apology and then nothing since, so no actual discussion as was promised.

Comment: @smci It appears my optimism was misplaced. I have edited the positivity out of the title but left the remaining text in place, albeit with a short note about the negative developments.

Comment: This new CoC seems like trying to kill a fly with a hammer. Obligatory pronouns have little to do with respect for people. For uncommon pronouns, it should be respected when others have discomfort in using them. This is not pronoun-fobia but can be reasonable. The use of 'they' has strong associations with plural (even when it has a history of singular), and novelties like xe, zir, ne might turn social norms into a Christmas tree. If a person tries to avoid using these terms, without avoiding the person or having problems with his/her/their identity, then this should be equally respectable.

Comment: @Martijn, personally I definitely understand some weirdness/discomfort with neopronouns (there are a *lot* of variations) and think the rules about people avoiding pronouns period are a little on the heavy-handed side. But I want to strongly reinforce that – particularly for they/them which it seems the *vast* majority of nonbinary people now prefer – it does _not_ feel very respectful to say 'oh, I respect your gender, but I respect _the sanctity of the English language_ more'. (Not saying that's what you said, but hopefully you can see how it can be hurtful to people.)

Comment: @Martijn right, but that's saying "I respect you but not enough to make a [relatively minor accommodation](https://www.npr.org/2019/08/06/744121321/even-a-grammar-geezer-like-me-can-get-used-to-gender-neutral-pronouns) in how I use language when interacting with you." Can you see that this doesn't really feel like very much respect? (As an aside, I recently heard someone fairly senior and respected in my field tell a story about their "daughter" and how "she" requested to be referred to as they, but "I have grammatical problems with that." This did not make me feel very welcome in the field.)

Comment: I can see that it might hurt, since the pronouns relate to gender classification and this might misrepresents ones identity which is hurtful when it happens often. However asking people to use pronouns which are weird to them should be a request and not a demand. And especially a rule set in  code of conduct goes much too far than neccesary and could be detrimental when it states that preferred pronouns are *obligatory*.

Comment: I guess the point where we disagree is that you – and apparently a margin of hundreds of people on meta.SE – believe that a rule requiring that users take minor actions to not hurt a marginalized minority "goes much too far than necessary." I suppose there's not much more to say after that.

Comment: It is not neccesarily disrespectful when a person  avoids the use of pronouns on SE. I do this often, sometimes I write he/she when gender is unknown but also sometimes I try to avoid the need to write the pronoun altogether. Demanding that I should use 'they' and me not following up on that has little to do with me not respecting others 'by misgendering'.

Comment: However,  it depends a lot on the weight that people give to this (how much does it help them when they have their own individual pronoun) and how much they demand (where does it stop?). There's large variations worldwide (like French vous/toi German Sie/du while English has only you) and on an international forum it can not (should not) be placed into a single specific rule. The problem with the rule is also that it turns gray into black-white. We should have respect for others based on plausible demands. If a person *needs* a lot to be called 'they' then they gets it, but spaghetti monster?

Comment: *"a rule requiring that users take minor actions to not hurt a marginalized minority "goes much too far than necessary.""* I do not believe that the minor actions go too far (although I find them debatable and I will debate them, but in personal live I suspend judgement on most things and will just go with the flow) but I believe that the rule goes too far because it does more than necessary to reach the goal. It's like 'killing a fly with a sledge hammer'. It is the wrong way to get this language change.

Comment: @Martijn After Twitter's recent clarification that persistent misgendering counts as abuse, there were very clear instances of transphobes "not misgendering" by either persistently using "they" after a trans woman had made it clear she uses "she," or doing things like putting after each usage to expressly indicate it was "forced speech." (Of course it's impossible to ever find anything again on Twitter, though I just tried for a bit.) This is what the COC is trying to avoid. Nobody is going to be banned for saying "OP" unless it's a clear, persistent pattern of not using someone's pronouns.

Comment: That twitter stuf is more like intentional bullying and has little to do with regular daily language use. By the way, *you* can not say it is a minor adjustment, like  others can not say the wrong use of pronouns is not hurtful. It is up to the person who has to make the adjustment to decide how much the adjustment is. It is just as disrespectful for A to make this adjustment a requirement for B (and not acknowledge B's pain of the adjustment) as it is disrespectfull for B to not make the adjustment (and not acknowledge A's pain of the pronouns interferring with gender identity).

Comment: If people would be more respectfully to LBTQI would the use of pronouns also be less of an issue? Women  on StackExchange hide their female identity and the first time they 'come out' and say that other's can use 'she' is an important moment (at least, I read about an example of that on meta or in a blog). All these problems about gender related pronouns are actually not problems about pronouns but indirectly it is more about gender. It disturbs me that recently in Twitter/Facebook-land it has become so much about these symbolic issues rather than the real issue which is general intolerance.

Comment: @Martijn It is 100% about the general environment, of which pronouns are the most easy-to-talk-about part. My reaction today more or less agrees with [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335190/621523). I realize that it doesn't feel like that to people who it doesn't affect. But respecting pronouns has become (in English) a strong issue that yes, may be mostly symbolic, but it's also _an actual thing that hurts people_ and is [very much intertwined with everyday acceptance for trans people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335098/621523).

Comment: @Martijn Sure, you can [say](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/fyi-a-second-apology-from-se-has-been-posted#comment19219_5774) that it's impossible to weigh someone's acknowledgement-of-gender-related pain against someone else feeling uncomfortable by being asked to adjust their language. Logically, I suppose I can't say anything to counter that, at least not that couldn't be used from the "other side." Emotionally, I want you to know that _even you saying that is painful to me and people like me_. I don't think I can say anything further that will be useful here.

Comment: I believe you should not make it personal when I argue that << but that's saying "I respect you but not enough to make a relatively minor accommodation in how I use language when interacting with you." >> is a statement that may incorrectly represent "a relatively minor accommodation". All I am saying is that *we* can not make this judgement 'minor' for others.

Comment: In addition I believe that we should not see it as an act of intentional disrespect (twitter bullies are different from persons that just feel uncomfortable with the pronouns intrinsicly and not because they have something against LHBTI).

Comment: The acceptance has become intertwined with the use of pronouns (and maybe it has become circular: it hurts because it's disrespect and it's disrespect because it hurts). But this goes *both* ways. The pronouns have become important for LHBTI as a sign of respect. But in the other direction this now turns people that have otherwise nothing against LHBTI into disrespectfull people when they do not like to use pronouns. And now since the Monica-SE quarrel it also has become disrespectfull to just state that it is problematic (even when you accomodate). This is going into the wrong direction.

Comment: @Martijn, I'd suggest you read the discussion on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335267/621523) – I think ColeValleyGirl did a better job explaining essentially my point of view than I did.

Comment: @anon I get there might be pain due to people not using certain pronouns (e.g. because people association with the acceptation of gender/identity). I am just bringing in that we don't need a forum to police on whether or not people are nice to each other, in terms of very strict descriptions of the use of pronouns. When I wish to use 'h*' instead of 'they', for instance, because it is shorter (like you use martijn instead of martijnweterings) then this is *my* choice and it is not about 'it's not so hard or little effort' but about *invading* my personal use of language.

Comment: The goal is acceptance and language is only the means to get to it. This CoC seems to make language the goal by putting so much stress on it. That is in my opinion a wrong approach. In the first place it is about the respect and this can not be captured in strict and one-sided rules that favour, beforehand, only one side of the parties involved. We are not all like spouses rejecting certain pronouns *because we do not like the gender concept*. Bad intentions, like the people on twitter, is now assumed *beforehand* for situations where people omit the use of pronouns in a certain way.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings, I've been using the short version because I didn't know doing so might bother you (and it gave me a few more characters to work with). Now that you've sort-of indicated it does, I won't anymore. If you established more clearly that it does and I continued to use the short version, that would be bad behavior on my part. This is _exactly_ analogous to the pronouns situation.

Comment: I am not offended but it might have been, and this is just to show how conversations on internet are not so easy (btw you still do not know whether I prefer martijnweterings, maye I prefer an additional 'sir' 'prof' 'lord' or some other title). The point's it doesn't matter because you did not behave with bad intentions. This's the same way for the majority on stackexchange, there is no bad intentions with using pronouns in a certain way. The persistence that other's should abide with some strict rule because personal problems, and suggest it's only little effort, is invasive and disrespectful

Comment: Most p on StackExchange have good intentions and would not have problems with any rule that explains how to be polite to each other. Sort of house rules (like in many places the ways to speak to each other might be different, just see the many ways to start and end a letter, and need some explanation). Mi problem with the new CoC is that it pressures people to use a very particular house rule, instead of just stating that w all should be polite. How would ya think about a rule that *forces* that ya should use another's preferred way to greet instead of giving yo freedom to handle it yourselve?

Comment: @anon Interesting conversation. I am curious about your position on the following: if somebody is fine with saying "he" or "she" or "they" correctly as requested by another person, but refuses to say "ze" and similar invented pronouns (and would e.g. say "they" instead, or reformulate without pronouns), would you say this is also disrespectful and should be condemned?

Comment: @amoeba, I don’t use a neopronoun, and I don’t think I really know anyone who does. It’s not super common. (I’ve been to a few in-person trans groups and am moderately active on trans Twitter; I’ve definitely seen a few accounts on the latter with neopronouns, but not many. My hunch is eg on tumblr it’s probably more common.) So, probably better to ask someone who does. My personal feeling is that using “they” for someone who’s explicitly requested, say, “ze” and not “they” is *rude* but perhaps not the same category as *misgendering*. But I’m really not the right person to ask.

Comment: @amoeba, also see [this short conversation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335308/621523) which I think has some useful points.

Answer (score 15):

It has become obvious that the second beautifully (management-style) written apology is not sincere.

The follow up actions are not only dissatisfying, but in addition the StackExchange employees are even [joking about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335173/) the moderators quitting.

StackExchange is displaying a lack of talent in how to deal with this difficult matter and is doing more harm instead of trying to do good. And in the process they show that they do not care about their community (and this issue with the change of the Code of Conduct is just a last drop in the bucket).

---

I believe that moderators resigning seems not to be enough. I guess that a larger signal is necessary like a lot of users going on strike.

I myself have little power (just 1% of the answers here) but I will kick off and see if many want to join the list and make StackExchange understand better that they have not been behaving well to the community and have not been leading by example (showing how to be respectful).

No more answers from:

- Martijn Weterings (pseudonym StackExchangeStrike aka Sextus Empiricus, following [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336029/389297))
- Aksakal
- mdewey (including from review queues)

---

*To any person that is not identifying as he/she. Note that this post is not against the LGBTQ community. It is against the disrespect of StackExchange towards their contributors. I hope that respect may come to the LGBTQ community without this respect being fabricated by a management that distrusts their contributors and creates hollow draconian rules (that do nothing to change non-accepting people into accepting people, or worse might do the opposite), but instead by a community on StackExchange that is typically caring about others and is just trying to help.*

Comment: But what are the demands?

Comment: It is difficult to put this into exact words (and I realize now that this drifts towards a yellow vest movement) but for me, the demand would be that the contributors to StackOverflow/StackExchange should be having more influence. Either by listening better to them (and show this in response) or by giving them more explicit and effective power in the decision process (although this second option I do not see happen for a commercial company).

Comment: The changes in the code of conduct an-sich are not so bad (just a bit odd specific focus on gender issues). But the FAQ relating to it goes out of hand. It is describing mores, what should be unwritten rules, in fine detail and examples with a one-sided point of view (no freedom for the community). The matter of bigotry explained in this FAQ is focussed on gender issues (ignoring religion), down to the extreme an obligatory accepting of neopronouns (not that this occurs in Overflow/Math/Phys/other-tech, but that does not change that the nonrespectful rule *is* there).

Comment: In social groups it's give and take. We wheigh our rights agains other's rights. Strict rules like the FAQ cut through the dynamics of this process. Most people don't care about pronouns like 'they' when this helps a sufficiently large group. But when you make it out of balance (e.g. neopronouns, or obligatory 'they' as standard genderneutral language when referring to a person with unknown gender, which is like almost everybody given the many anonimous users) then you get opposition. Instead, let the community develop the details more naturally, instead of these condescending pre-chewed laws.

Comment: @Scortchi the two demands from [this recent post from Monica](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336526/) are a minimum requirement (in addition it must become clear that this can not happen again and SE will take contributors more seriously instead of [regarding them as disposables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335173/se-inc-director-of-public-qa-retweets-bad-faith-misrepresentative-tweet)).