# Possible loss of some images from posts owing to Imgur's plan to remove old, unowned content with low views

Tags: discussion

[Imgur TOS change on May 15th 2023 could cause the loss of thousands of Stack Exchange images!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388556/225179)

Note first that images with `https://i.stack.imgur.com` or `https://stack.imgur.com` URLs (those automatically uploaded through the GUI interface) are not at risk. Images with `https://i.imgur.com` or `https://imgur.com` URLs are perhaps at risk—we don't know which are owned by an Imgur account, & criteria around age & no. of views haven't yet been determined ("We plan to use a combination of total views and recent views, among other criteria, to define content as inactive"—[Imgur Terms of Service Update [April 19, 2023]](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/14415587638029-Imgur-Terms-of-Service-Update-April-19-2023-)).

Glorfindel has [already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388726/225179) written & run a script to copy images from `https://i.imgur.com` to `https://stack.imgur.com`. There were 872 successfully copied, so these can be replaced if the current link breaks, or preëmptively—S.E. *may* be willing to help by automatically replacing them. There were 28 that could not be copied—for many of these it seems the link is already broken for some reason. (If anyone wants to find them, the post IDs are not given but you can use the site search with the URL e.g. `url:"https://i.imgur.com/48kXw9k.gif"`.)

[A site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3ahttps%3a%2f%2fimgur.com) shows 180 posts with `https://imgur.com` URLs. I hope Glorfindel will find the time to run his script for these too. [He did, just now, & there are a few that could not be copied—I'll post these when I get the chance.]

In fine I don't think we have a huge problem, given that 80% or so are now banked, that of the remainder only some will be removed (if they haven't already been), & that only some will be all that important to the post. On the other hand we only have eleven days before some may start to disappear.

Comment: We may be able to use the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) to find archived versions.  We could then update the links to WM, or copy the images to `stack.imgur`.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica: Yes - in fact Glorfindel's script, when it comes across a broken link, tries to find an archived version; & if it succeeds, uploads the image to `stack.imgur`. I shouldn't like to have to do that manually for many, though.

Comment: It seems that we do not need to get into action quickly do we? The images are allready copied for the i.imgur.com url's (and will also be soon for imgur.com url's?). The two remaining issues seem to be 1) how to change all the hyperlinks (but the copying has already been done), and 2) how to fix the images that could not be copies (but they are not on imgur anymore anyway).

Comment: +1 I have wondered from the inception of this site whether reliance in Imgur would eventually break it.  How evanescent *all* our work is... .  For years now I have been routinely scraping CV of my own posts and archiving them because eventually CV will disappear, too.  I was very active on other technical sites in the 90's and 00's, including some I hosted personally, *and none of them are still around.*

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus: That's right, except that we have no guarantee that Glorfindel will find time to run his script for `imgur.com` URLs. (He's not an S.E. employee, just extraordinarily helpful.)

Comment: @whuber: Even the back-ups don't include images, only the links to them: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4799/17230

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica I don't use backups: I scrape the entire thing.

Comment: Maybe related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394833/updates-to-the-acceptable-use-policy, in particular the last paragraph about scraping.

Answer (score 4):

#### Two notes

**1**

For the record the 28 that did not get copied are these:

from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/master/upload-imgur-images.md

For Cross Validated

| Frequency | URL | Failure | Fixed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/48kXw9k.gif | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | fixed Reduced size a lot (17.5 Mb to 2 Mb), uploaded to i.stack.imgur, & edited link |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/5IWH9Qd.png | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/7NvnRJl.png | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/9tY9sLE.png | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/ALQfTcs.jpg | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/DJsKegq.jpg | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/EfcnrIf.png | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/Hudw20v.jpg | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/MC4AT8E.jpg | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/MQLsxMQ.jpg | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/VasiB3e.jpg | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/VpIj86Z.mp4 | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | Inessential: the relevant snapshot from the linked animation is already embedded with an `i.stack.imgur` URL. |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/Zqgbc.png | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/a/Xd9JcHg | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | Fixed (OP had already provided text) |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/bB5iP6u.png | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | Reduced size slightly, uploaded to `i.stack.imgur`, & edited link |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/eyRBF7C.jpg/ | APIException: You didn't enter a valid URL | Fixed - re-uploaded image (which the script hadn't done on account of the trailing black-slash) & edited post. |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/fdX26L7.jpg | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/g8ERIjw.jpg | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/hYBiBwm.jpg | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/iv2eTlX.png | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/jqfjcwR.jpg | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/kHpvTQH.png | APIException: Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image | Reduced size slightly, uploaded to `i.stack.imgur`, & edited link |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/lJZM1mc.jpg | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/pon8eKL.png | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/q18e0zh.jpg | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/rN4eGRU.png | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/uyZMCLp.png | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/vW6UuLB.png | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. |  |

For cross validated meta

| Frequency | URL | Failure | Fixed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRR8V.png | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | fixed |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/RDR9I.png | FatalException: Wayback Machine can't be reached. | not fixed earliest snapshot from 2013 already broken https://web.archive.org/web/20130515000000*/https://i.imgur.com/RDR9I.png |

**2**

I started searching my own posts and found an i.imgur.com image that I re-uploaded to imgur using the stackexchange accounts, but that was unnecessary.

I could have searched the list from Glorfindel and used the new link instead.

Comment: I fixed one of these broken images (it was available on wayback internet database but not easily found) and failed on another https://i.imgur.com/RDR9I.png (the database image from 2013 is alread the removed.png image). I am afraid that this is gonna be a manual job for the other cases as well.

Comment: Thanks, this is v. useful. I note there are a couple that need shrinking. The [`magick` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html) might be useful.

Comment: For the two png's that were over 2 MiB, I was able to reduce their size slightly using the `image_scale` function (with no apparent degradation of quality). Dealing with gifs looks to be more complicated in `magick`; [Gifsicle](https://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle) is another option.

Comment: The large gif image from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/583472/ could be changed by scaling down to 4 colours. (ping to @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica)

Comment: Smashing! (How did you do that, by the way?)

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica I used gifsicle with some command that I found on stack overflow or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of the images that weren't copied to the `i.stack.imgur.com` domain on the latest run of Glorfindel's script (now including `imgur.com` as well as `i.imgur.com` URLs):

#### Uncertainties

| Frequency | URL | Replacement | Post IDs | Fixed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/48kXw9k.gif | Not uploaded but archived as https://web.archive.org/web/20230503063307/https://i.imgur.com/48kXw9k.gif | 583472 | Fixed |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/bB5iP6u.png | Not uploaded but archived as https://web.archive.org/web/20230503063357/https://i.imgur.com/bB5iP6u.png | 348160 | Fixed |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/kHpvTQH.png | Not uploaded but archived as https://web.archive.org/web/20230505174634/https://i.imgur.com/kHpvTQH.png | 349146 | Fixed |

#### Failures

| Frequency | URL | Failure | Post IDs | Fixed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/9tY9sLE.png | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 273446 |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/ALQfTcs.jpg | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 94690 |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/DJsKegq.jpg | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 94542 |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/EfcnrIf.png | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 358226 |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/Hudw20v.jpg | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 94690 |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/MC4AT8E.jpg | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 94690 |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/MQLsxMQ.jpg | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 394939 |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/VasiB3e.jpg | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 423420 |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/VpIj86Z.mp4 | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 499867 |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/a/Xd9JcHg | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 375796 | Fixed |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/eyRBF7C.jpg/ | APIException: You didn't enter a valid URL | 61711 | Fixed |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/fdX26L7.jpg | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 394939 |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/g8ERIjw.jpg | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 94690 |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/hYBiBwm.jpg | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 94542 |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/iv2eTlX.png | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 294432 |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/jqfjcwR.jpg | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 94690 |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/lJZM1mc.jpg | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 394939 |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/pon8eKL.png | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 273446 |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/q18e0zh.jpg | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 94542 |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/uyZMCLp.png | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 273799 |  |
| 1 | https://i.imgur.com/vW6UuLB.png | Not found in Wayback Machine. | 340199 |  |
| 1 | https://imgur.com/ | ProcessImageException: com.stackexchange.toolbox.editor.DownloadFailedException: Invalid Content-Type text/html returned for https://web.archive.org/web/20230509193115/https://imgur.com/ | 96997 |  |
| 1 | https://imgur.com/9wWdcjr | DownloadFailedException: Image not found on imgur image page. | 151482 |  |
| 1 | https://imgur.com/a/U9OVAFO | DownloadFailedException: Image not found on imgur image page. | 601146 |  |
| 1 | https://imgur.com/a/dTXM9a2 | ProcessImageException: com.stackexchange.toolbox.editor.DownloadFailedException: Broken image, an error image is served instead. | 465738 |  |
| 1 | https://imgur.com/a/j0VXwZK | ProcessImageException: com.stackexchange.toolbox.editor.DownloadFailedException: Broken image, an error image is served instead. | 367174 |  |
| 1 | https://imgur.com/a/zb2hM | DownloadFailedException: Image not found on imgur image page. | 59248 |  |
| 1 | https://imgur.com/gqHQhVI | DownloadFailedException: Image not found on imgur image page. | 465738 |  |
| 1 | https://imgur.com/vUPjsxI | DownloadFailedException: Image not found on imgur image page. | 232858 |  |
| 1 | https://imgur.com/vsb | DownloadFailedException: com.stackexchange.toolbox.RequestFailedException: Request failed: 404 - Not Found | 161898 |  |
| 1 | https://web.archive.org/web/20170815001603/https://imgur.com/a/g4CdU | ProcessImageException: com.stackexchange.toolbox.editor.DownloadFailedException: com.stackexchange.toolbox.RequestFailedException: Request failed: 404 - NOT FOUND | 297905 |  |